# How to move the whole sub-collection in Cloud Firestore using flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I Know that to move a document, we have to copy and paste. But the sub-collections are missed from copy->pasting.

So how do I copy and paste all the documents in the collection?

from path - /main/issueOpen/list/-Lb2yhvNLN6NsvCXAGyM/chat/[has lots of Documents]

to path - /main/issueClosed/list/-Lb2yhvNLN6NsvCXAGyM/chat/[all moved here]

```
...
    Future<Null> closeIssue() async {
        DocumentReference fromDocument = await Firestore.instance
            .collection("main").document("issueOpen").collection("list")
            .document(chatId);
        DocumentReference toDocument = await Firestore.instance
            .collection("main").document("issueClosed").collection("list")
            .document(chatId);
        fromDocument.get().then((datasnapshot) {
          if (datasnapshot.exists) {
            toDocument.setData(datasnapshot.data).whenComplete(() {
            }).catchError((e) => print(e));
          }
        });
      }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

All read operations in Firestore are shallow. Reading a document, does not read any data from subcollections of that document.

This means that to move a document and its subcollections to a new location, you will have to copy that document *and* copy all documents from its subcollections.

If the number of documents is not too large, consider doing this in a transaction, so that it happens atomically on the server.